# How to create a vector index of only unique images in a large random image dataset using FAISS?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, embedding, faiss

I have been following [this blog post](https://medium.com/@jeremy-k/unlocking-openai-clip-part-3-optimizing-image-embedding-storage-and-retrieval-pickle-vs-faiss-25d0f02c049d) to create vector embeddings for a dataset of public domain images that I have downloaded from flickr.

Everything is working as expected, I am able to search through the image dataset and find images most closely related to the word "dog", "cat", etc...

Unfortunately, there are a lot of duplicate images contained within my dataset.

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow ignore all but 1 image file with similar embeddings when I am preprocessing the images into the vector index if that makes any sense?

Relevant python code below:

```
from PIL import Image
import torch
import clip
import numpy as np
import faiss
import os

#read all image names
images = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./dataset'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('png'):
            images.append(root  + '/'+ file)

#Load CLIP
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
model, preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", device=device)

#Define the emb variable to store embeddings
emb = {}

#Extract embeddings and store them in the emb variable
for img in images:
    with torch.no_grad():
        image = preprocess(Image.open(img)).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        image_features = model.encode_image(image)
        emb[img] = image_features

#Create Faiss index using FlatL2 type. 512 is the number of dimensions of each vectors
index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(512)
#Convert embeddings and add them to the index
for key in emb:
    #Convert to numpy
    vector = emb[key].detach().cpu().numpy()
    #Convert to float32 numpy
    vector = np.float32(vector)
    #Normalize vector: important to avoid wrong results when searching
    faiss.normalize_L2(vector)
    #Add to index
    index.add(vector)

#Store the index locally
faiss.write_index(index,"vector.index")
```